# php from action value get from drop-down list

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

My Goal is get two drop down values and 1. pass them to `action` and 2. pass them to `$_POST` to next `.php` page. In short i want to select `action` php page using `drop-down` menu.

What i am doing wrong here, whatever i select from `page` drop-down menu it always default select `page1.php`

```
<html>
<body>

<select name='page'>
<option value='page1.php'>page1</option>
<option value='page2.php'>page2</option>
</select>

<form name="page" method="post" action="<?php echo $_POST['page']; ?>">
<?php
// DB connection info:
include 'db_connection.php';

$sql = "SHOW tables";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='param1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Tables_in_radius'] . "'>" . $row['Tables_in_radius'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>

<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['param1'])){
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `page` select is outside of the form so it won't be submitted with the form.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? Why do you think you're doing something wrong?

Comment: You can use javascript (onchange event) to set form action,see example: http://jsfiddle.net/sp9oav9u/ (inspect HTML output to see change of action attr). Then you can post your data to php, via submit button...

Comment: @Andrew because every time i select whatever `page` from drop-down. it always selecting default `page1.php`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - I have tried to put under `<from>` but same result.

Answer (score 0):

1) Place the drop down inside the form.

2) if(isset($_POST['param1']))   <-- What is param1 ?
 change it to : $_POST['page']

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.  Any additional explanation or elaboration would also be helpful.